# Trying to get back a score from a quiz

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason only the score0 wants to increment. Although the two for-loops seem identical (really sorry if I'm wrong). So the totScore just gets the value from the score0 variable. But ofcourse I want totScore to get value form both variables so to get the total score of the quiz.

Also, why does it add 4 to the score0 variable when I wrote  `score0 += 1;`, that doesn't make any sence to me.

If you change my code alot please don't use any JQuery.
Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form id='quizForm'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h3>How many letters are there in 'FB'?</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="question0" value="A" />2<br>
            <input type="radio" name="question0" value="B" />1<br>
            <input type="radio" name="question0" value="C" />3<br>
            <input type="radio" name="question0" value="D" />4<br>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h3>How many letters are there in 'IBM'?</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="A" />2<br>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="B" />1<br>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="C" />3<br>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="D" />4<br>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>

<button onclick="showScore()">Show results
</button>
        <script>    
        //Score and answer variables
        var score1 = 0;
        var score0 = 0;
        var totScore = 0;
        var answers = ["A","C"]
//function to calculate the score.
function getScore() {
    // some arrays and stuff
    userInput1 = new Array(10);
    userInput0 = new Array(10);
    var question0s = document.getElementsByName("question0");

   //for loop to see which radio was checked
   for (var i = 0; i < question0s.length; i++) {
        if (question0s[i].checked) {
            userInput0[0] = question0s[i].value;
    }
    if (userInput0[0] == answers[0]) {
        // Only god knows why the hell I have to divide 4
       score0 += 1 / 4;
    }
    else if (userInput0[0] != answers [0]){
        //so that user can't just switch back and fourth from inputs to get higher score.
        score0 -= 1 ;
    }
    }
    //if user has changed her answer multiple times she will get an answer with a negative value. I don't want that, so if score is less than 0 it turns to 0.
    if (score0 < 0){
        score0 = score0 * 0;
    }

    var question1s = document.getElementsByName("question1");
   //for loop to see which radio was checked
   for (var y = 0; y < question1s.length; y++) {
        if (question1s[y].checked) {
            userInput1[0] = question1[y].value;
    }
    if (userInput1[0] == answers[0]) {
       score1 += 1;
    }
    else if (userInput1[0] != answers [0]){
    //so that user can't just switch back and fourth from inputs to get higher score.
        score1 -= 1 ;
    }
    }
    if (score1 < 0){
        //if user has changed her answer multiple times she will get an answer with a negative value. I don't want that, so if score is less than 0 it turns to 0.
        score1 = score1 * 0;
    }
    //getting score from all different questions
    totScore += score1 + score0;
}
//checking for changes in the form
var quizForm = document.getElementById('quizForm');
quizForm.addEventListener("change", function(){
    getScore();
});


// onclick function
function showScore (){
    alert (totScore);
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As to why you are not getting proper processing, you have an invalid variable `question1` here:

```
userInput1[0] = question1[y].value;
```

Now let's fix this and do better.

First off, you have a number of global variables so let's get that under a simple namespace and call it `quiz`.

Get the click handler out of the markup and create a listener for that.

Now as for your logic, you are looping through the radio buttons.  Now the way radio buttons work is that only one can be selected SO, let's use that to our advantage an not do the loop at all.

With the radio buttons, if one is NOT selected yet, then it will be NULL using our new selection technique so we can use that to tell if both the questions have been answered and then if that IS true, we can put scores in.  Otherwise, they get no score (score is 0) until all the questions ARE answered (not NULL).

```
//Score and answer variables=
 var quiz = {
   score0: 0,
   score1: 0,
   totalScore: 0,
   answers: ["A", "C"],
   maxScore: 2,
   tries: 0
 };
 //function to calculate the score.
 function getScore() {
   var answer0 = document.querySelector('input[name="question0"]:checked');
   quiz.score0 = answer0 != null && quiz.answers[0] == answer0.value ? 1 : 0;
   var answer1 = document.querySelector('input[name="question1"]:checked');
   quiz.score1 = answer1 != null && quiz.answers[1] == answer1.value ? 1 : 0;
   // if either is null, not all answered
   if (answer0 != null && answer1 != null) {
     // if previous tries, subtract how many
     if (quiz.tries) {
       quiz.totalScore = quiz.totalScore ? quiz.totalScore - quiz.tries : 0;
       quiz.totalScore = quiz.totalScore < 0 ? 0 : quiz.totalScore ;//0 if negative
     } else {
       quiz.totalScore = quiz.score1 + quiz.score0;
     }
     quiz.tries++;
   }
 }
 // onclick function
 function showScore() {
   alert(quiz.totalScore + " in tries: " + quiz.tries);
 }
 // add listeners
 //checking for changes in the form
 var quizForm = document.getElementById('quizForm');
 quizForm.addEventListener("change", function() {
   getScore();
 });
 var resultButton = document.getElementById('results');
 resultButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
   showScore();
 });
```

Try the above out here: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/qx4hLjLq/2/

You could also do more with this by putting that in the `quiz` something like this:

```
 //Score and answer variables=
 var quiz = {
   totalScore: 0,
   tries: 0,
   maxScore: 2,
   answered: 0,
   questions: [{
     question: {},
     name: "question0",
     score: 0,
     answer: "A"
   }, {
     question: {},
     name: "question1",
     score: 0,
     answer: "C"
   }],
   checkQuestion: function(q) {
     q.score = q.question != null && q.answer == q.question.value ? 1 : 0;
   },
   //function to calculate the score.
   getScore: function() {
     this.answered = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < this.questions.length; i++) {
       var sel = 'input[name="' + this.questions[i].name + '"]:checked';
       this.questions[i].question = document.querySelector(sel);
       this.checkQuestion(this.questions[i]);
       this.answered = this.questions[i].question ? this.answered + 1 : this.answered;
     }
     console.dir(this);

     // if either is null, not all answered
     if (this.answered == this.questions.length) {
       for (var i = 0; i < this.questions.length; i++) {
         this.totalScore = this.totalScore + this.questions[i].score;
       }
       if (this.tries) {
         this.totalScore = this.tries && this.totalScore ? this.totalScore - this.tries : 0;
         this.totalScore = this.totalScore < 0 ? 0 : this.totalScore; //0 if negative
       }
       this.tries++;
     }
   },

   // onclick function
   showScore: function() {
     var t = "";
     if (this.answered != this.questions.length) {
       t = "Not all questions ansered!"
     } else {
       t = this.totalScore + " in tries: " + this.tries;
     }
     alert(t);
   }
 };
 // add listeners
 //checking for changes in the form
 var quizForm = document.getElementById('quizForm');
 quizForm.addEventListener("change", function() {
   quiz.getScore();
 });
 var resultButton = document.getElementById('results');
 resultButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
   quiz.showScore();
 });
```

Second example in action: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/qx4hLjLq/4/

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to simply get the result from the test, use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h3>How many letters are there in 'FB'?</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="question0"/>1<br>
            <input type="radio" name="question0"/>2<br>
            <input type="radio" name="question0"/>3<br>
            <input type="radio" name="question0"/>4<br>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h3>How many letters are there in 'IBM'?</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="question1"/>1<br>
            <input type="radio" name="question1"/>2<br>
            <input type="radio" name="question1"/>3<br>
            <input type="radio" name="question1"/>4<br>
        </li>
    </ul>
<button onclick="calculate()">Submit</button>
<script>
function calculate(){
    var answers = [1, 2];
    var score = 0;
    var question0s = document.getElementsByName("question0");
    var question1s = document.getElementsByName("question1");
    if (question0s[answers[0]].checked == true) {
        score++;
    }
    if (question1s[answers[1]].checked == true) {
        score++;
    }
    alert ("You got " + score + " out of " + answers.length + ".");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like you're calling the script every time an answer changes, and this is very inefficient. I'm only calling when all the answers have been made and the user presses submit.

And the reason why that is adding 4 times is because if you set your first answer to A, it writes it to `userinput0` and doesn't get changed anymore since the answer was the only one checked, and it repeats the amount of choices there are, in which there were 4. Thus you are repeating that assignment statement 4 times so you are adding 4.

Comment: Oh yeah, that code is so much better than mine lol. Thanks, really helpful!

Comment: If my response answers all your questions, just check the tick underneath the large vote number. It helps me and marks this question as answered.